# AngularJS and Sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm very new to AngularJS and I'm trying to figure out the "best practices" method for including the navigation and sidebar.

I'm guessing the approach is similar to Worpdress.  I would  have a "header" file with content that is displayed on each page, and only call a sidebar (sidebar.html) when the template needs it.  At the moment I have a main.html file and I want to include a sidebar.

Should the the sidebar be a separate html file?  And how do I call that file when it is need?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty broad question but I'll give it a go.

Angular is built for SPA (Single Page Application). Therefore, you only really need one `index` page that will have a sidebar + header. Your content will be in separate template files that will be loaded by Angular's `$route` service.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I know it's a basic question, but the docs are not that easy to use. I'll look more into the $route service.  Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, angular has a steep learning curve but it's worth it. It forces you to use the right design principles which can be frustrating at times but it's worth it in the long-run.